# What is the difference between Skip_build and test_without_building on Fastlane/Scanfile

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

What is the difference between Skip_build and test_without_building on Fastlane/Scanfile?

I would really execute my test cases without building everytime, I have several schemes that are executed on a shell script in a loop.   I don't want to build for every iteration.

Does anybody tried those parameters before?

Answer (score 5):

The `skip_build` parameter will omit the `build` command from the generated `xcodebuild` command that ultimately gets executed by *scan*. This means that if there is a built product in DerivedData, it will use it instead of recompiling your app. If there is no build product in DerivedData, it will rebuild the product.

The `test_without_building` parameter is the equivalent of the `--test-without-building` flag that you can pass to `xcodebuild`. This allows you to pass other flags to the command to point to the product under test.